# jQuery coin slider plugin

Tags: jquery, html

I was trying to implement jQuery coin slider plugin on my web page. I downloaded the requisite coin slider script from here. http://workshop.rs/projects/coin-slider/

Though it should have been working but I am not getting the images on my webpage. Here's the full html of my the page where I am trying this. http://pastebin.com/s60ju1cf

Is any thing wrong in here? Why am not getting the images on the webpage?

Comment: I suggest that you try to narrow it down a bit more, I don't know about anyone else, but that's a lot of html to sift through.

Comment: Done. Here's the new HTML page: http://pastebin.com/s60ju1cf

Answer (score 1):

Cipher, I think you need to double check your work. That link you included for the plugin has some very easy to follow examples. I've worked with many 3rd party plugins and it appears that they did a very good job of showing you how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The author doesn't include jquery in his download so you need to either point to it on some CDN or download a copy locally.